# Printing a pattern in C using loops

Tags: c

The pattern to be printed(for user input n) is:

```
                        4 4 4 4 4 4 4  
                        4 3 3 3 3 3 4   
                        4 3 2 2 2 3 4   
                        4 3 2 1 2 3 4   
                        4 3 2 2 2 3 4   
                        4 3 3 3 3 3 4   
                        4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i,j,k,l,p,n,tc,i1,j1,k1;
    n=4;

    for(i=1;i<=n*2-1;i++)
    {
        p=n;
        if(i<=n)
        {
        for(j=1;j<=i-1;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",p);
            p--;
        }
        for(k=j;k<=n*2-j;k++)
            printf("%d ",p);
        for(l=k;l<=n*2-1;l++)
        {
            p++;
            printf("%d ",p);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            p=n;
            for(i1=1;i1<=n*2-i-1;i1++)
            {
                printf("%d ",p);
                p-=1;
            }
            for(j1=i1;j1<=n*2-i1;j1++)
                printf("%d ",p);
            for(k1=j1;k1<=n*2-1;k++)
            {
                p+=1;
                printf("%d ",p);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   return 0;
} //main
```

I am using a gcc 6.3 compiler and it is giving

```
Output File Size Exceeded
```

Where am I going wrong?I can't figure it out. I have tried this code in gcc 4.x and I was getting the correct output.

Comment: Is that a message generated by ggc during compiling/building?

Comment: Scanf() allows for many possible mistakes and misunderstandings. What happens if you hard code e.g. `n=4;` instead of scanf()? And please never ignore the return value of scanf().

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit for consistent indentation, it currently makes code interpretation needlessly hard.

Comment: BTW if you consider coordinates `x` and `y` that go from `-(n-1)` to `n-1` included, in each position the value to print is `max(abs(i), abs(j)) + 1`. Exploiting this fact the code becomes way simpler (indeed, it becomes just two nested loops).

Comment: (example of the above: https://ideone.com/q0qdxx)

Comment: @Matteo Italia thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your last loop, you increment the wrong variable.

```
for(k1=j1;k1<=n*2-1;k++){
   p+=1;
   printf("%d ",p);
}
```

change `k` to `k1`.

Comment: This really good shows how important are meaningful names for variables

Comment: And the value of limiting the scope of variables to the innermost loop (statement block) where they're used.